# Azure Device twins - HTTP or MQTT

Tags: c, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-sdk

I am using the Azure IoT device SDK for C to create a device application which communicates with the Azure IoT portal and updates its device twin.

Does the device twin use the **HTTP** or **MQTT** protocol for the communication?

I thought it was MQTT. However, I am receiving HTTP response status codes when I update the reported properties of a device twin.

When I am creating the device handler in my code, I specify MQTT as the transport protocol which is why i'm confused.

Code snippet to create the device handler :

```
IOTHUB_CLIENT_TRANSPORT_PROVIDER iothub_transport = MQTT_Protocol;
device_handler = IoTHubDeviceClient_CreateFromDeviceAuth(user_ctx.iothub_uri, user_ctx.device_id, iothub_transport
```

Code snippet to update the reported properties :

```
char* reportedProperties = SerializeEnergyInfoToJson(&info);// my own function which returns a JSON char* created from my data.
(void)IoTHubDeviceClient_SendReportedState(device_handler, (const unsigned char*)reportedProperties, strlen(reportedProperties), ReportedStateCallback, NULL);
```

Comment: Can you include the code snippet you use for updating the reported property, to make sure we understand correctly what you are doing?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Thanks for your reply. I've updated my question now with a snippet for updating the reported properties.

Answer (score 0):

Reporting property updates via the DeviceClient APIs will use the same protocol that you have specified when creating the DeviceClient. So in your case it will use MQTT.

If you want to learn more how this works under the covers by using MQTT directly, you can read up here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#update-device-twins-reported-properties

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't understand still why I am receiving an HTTP response.

Comment: What do you mean by HTTP response? The status codes are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#update-device-twins-reported-properties

Are you receiving something different than that?